# How to get all authority of authenticated user in OAuth2 Resource server

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

There is a resource server with the following configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ResourceServer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ResourceServer.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ResourceServer.class, args);
    }


    //@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, String> user(Principal user) {

        OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Authentication userAuthentication = oAuth2Authentication.getUserAuthentication();
        return (Map<String, String>) userAuthentication.getDetails();

    }

}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourcesServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices tokenService() {
        RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("http://localhost:8081/auth/account/getDetailUser");
        tokenService.setClientId("web");
        tokenService.setClientSecret("secret");
        return tokenService;
    }
}
```

and its the application.yml is:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.192.131:1521:hamed
        hikari:
            connection-test-query: SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
            minimum-idle: 1
            maximum-pool-size: 5
        driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        username: test
        password: test
        initialization-mode: always
    jpa:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG

server:
  port: 8083
  context-path: /micro1
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: web
      clientSecret: secret
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/authorize
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8081/auth/account/getDetailUser
```

It is necessary to mention that the flow is Authorization_code and with JDBC token store in UAA and the version of spring boot is 1.5.8.RELEASE
User is redirected to UAA and login successfully and is redirected to the client with code. Every thing till now is Ok but when I request to resource server where I want to get all authority of authenticated user like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, String> user(Principal user) {

        OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Authentication userAuthentication = oAuth2Authentication.getUserAuthentication();
        return (Map<String, String>) userAuthentication.getDetails();

    }
```

the following exception is raised:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken
>   cannot be cast to
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication

Where is wrong and what configuration is lost in resource server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like that

```
@GetMapping({"/user", "/me"})
public Map<String, Object> user(Principal principal){
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("name", principal.getName());
    if( principal instanceof OAuth2Authentication) {
        OAuth2Authentication oauth = (OAuth2Authentication)principal;
        map.put("authorities",oauth.getUserAuthentication().getAuthorities()
                               .stream()
                               .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
    return map;
}
```